# How to fill formula across

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

On Sheet 1 B4 I have the following formula:

```
=SUM(Sheet2!H4:N4)
```

I want to fill this formula to C4, so that it reads

```
=SUM(Sheet2!O4:U4).
```

[image: Sheet1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OFFSET function to stagger the starting column and extend the range 7 columns wide.

```
=sum(offset(Sheet2!$H4, 0, (column(A:A)-1)*7, 1, 7))
```

However, the OFFSET function is volatile and can contribute to a workbook's calculation lag. You can avoid this with a pair of INDEX functions.

```
=sum(index(Sheet2!$H4:$XFD4, 1, (column(A:A)-1)*7+1):index(Sheet2!$H4:$XFD4, 1, (column(A:A)-1)*7+7))
```

While that latter formula looks more complicated, it will actually require less calculations than the first.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked great and saved me so much time manually do each cell.